# A problem with integral constants and a differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, constants

[image]

This is the expression I have to solve for the axial velocity, represented by [image] .

Rearranging the expression I get:

[image]

After integration:

[image]

But my teacher ignores the brackets and comes to:

[image]

This is creating a lot of trouble because with brackets the problem becomes wrong...

I am supposed to get to:

[image]

, [image] and [image] are constants.

The delta sign is equivalent to the Leibnitz notation used before.

Thank you.

Comment: Your free variable is $r$, so $\Delta P \over \Delta z$ can be thought as constant and embeddable in $C_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when we know that the relation between $\mathcal{P}\left(\text{z}\right)$ and $\text{V}_\text{z}\left(\text{r}\right)$, looks like:

$$\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)=\mu\cdot\left\{\frac{1}{\text{r}}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\text{r}}\left(\text{r}\cdot\text{V}_\text{z}'\left(\text{r}\right)\right)\right\}$$

To simplify it:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\text{r}}\left(\text{r}\cdot\text{V}_\text{z}'\left(\text{r}\right)\right)=\text{V}_\text{z}'\left(\text{r}\right)+\text{r}\cdot\text{V}_\text{z}''\left(\text{r}\right)$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)=\mu\cdot\left\{\frac{1}{\text{r}}\cdot\left(\text{V}_\text{z}'\left(\text{r}\right)+\text{r}\cdot\text{V}_\text{z}''\left(\text{r}\right)\right)\right\}=\mu\cdot\left(\frac{\text{V}_\text{z}'\left(\text{r}\right)}{\text{r}}+\text{V}_\text{z}''\left(\text{r}\right)\right)$$

Let $\text{y}\left(\text{r}\right)=\text{V}_\text{z}'\left(\text{r}\right)$:

$$\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)=\mu\cdot\left(\frac{\text{y}\left(\text{r}\right)}{\text{r}}+\text{y}'\left(\text{r}\right)\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\text{r}}\left(\left|\text{r}\right|\cdot\text{y}\left(\text{r}\right)\right)\space\text{d}\text{r}=\int\frac{\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)\cdot\left|\text{r}\right|}{\mu}\space\text{d}\text{r}$$

Which leads to (assuming a real valued function):

$$\left|\text{r}\right|\cdot\text{y}\left(\text{r}\right)=\frac{\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)}{\mu}\int\left|\text{r}\right|\space\text{d}\text{r}=\frac{\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)}{\mu}\cdot\frac{\text{r}^2\cdot\text{sgn}\left(\text{r}\right)}{2}+\text{K}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{y}\left(\text{r}\right)=\frac{1}{\left|\text{r}\right|}\cdot\frac{\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)}{\mu}\cdot\frac{\text{r}^2\cdot\text{sgn}\left(\text{r}\right)}{2}+\text{K}$$

So, for $\text{V}_\text{z}\left(\text{r}\right)$ we get:

$$\text{V}_\text{z}\left(\text{r}\right)=\int\left\{\frac{1}{\left|\text{r}\right|}\cdot\frac{\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)}{\mu}\cdot\frac{\text{r}^2\cdot\text{sgn}\left(\text{r}\right)}{2}+\text{K}\right\}\space\text{d}\text{r}=\frac{\mathcal{P}'\left(\text{z}\right)}{2\mu}\cdot\int\frac{\text{r}^2\cdot\text{sgn}\left(\text{r}\right)}{\left|\text{r}\right|}\space\text{d}\text{r}+\text{K}\cdot\text{r}$$